# Convert stream into buffer?

Tags: node.js

How to convert stream into buffer in nodejs? Here is my code to parse a file in post request  in express.

```
app.post('/upload', express.multipart({
defer: true
}), function(req, res) {
req.form.on('part', function(part) {

//Here I want to convert the streaming part into a buffer.
//do something buffer-specific task

  var out = fs.createWriteStream('image/' + part.filename);
  part.pipe(out);
});

req.form.on('close', function() {
    res.send('uploaded!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`stream-to`](https://github.com/stream-utils/stream-to) module, which can convert a readable stream's data into an array or a buffer:

```js
var streamTo = require('stream-to');
req.form.on('part', function (part) {
    streamTo.buffer(part, function (err, buffer) {
        // Insert your business logic here
    });
});
```

If you want a better understanding of what's happening behind the scenes, you can implement the logic yourself, using a [`Writable` stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable). As a writable stream implementor, you only have to define one function: the [`_write` method](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback), that will be called every time some data is written to the stream. When the input stream is finished emitting data, the [`end` event](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) will be emitted: we'll then create a buffer using the [`Buffer.concat` method](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength).

```js
var stream = require('stream');
var converter = new stream.Writable();

// We'll store all the data inside this array
converter.data = [];
converter._write = function (chunk) {
    converter.data.push(chunk);
};

// Will be emitted when the input stream has ended, 
// i.e. no more data will be provided
converter.on('finish', function() {
    // Create a buffer from all the received chunks
    var b = Buffer.concat(this.data);

    // Insert your business logic here
});
```

Comment: For Writable streams, I believe the event is `finish`, not `end`. They both mean the same thing, but they need to be named differently because they coexist on Transform. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Comment: `stream-to` is deprecated and replaced with `stream-to-array` and `raw-body`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to

Comment: WHAT ABOUT with no modules or libraries?

Answer (score 49):

Instead of piping, you can attach `readable` and `end` event handlers to the `part` stream to read it:

```js
var buffers = [];
part.on('readable', function(buffer) {
  for (;;) {
    let buffer = part.read();
    if (!buffer) { break; }
    buffers.push(buffer);
  }
});
part.on('end', function() {
  var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
  ...do your stuff...

  // write to file:
  fs.writeFile('image/' + part.filename, buffer, function(err) {
    // handle error, return response, etc...
  });
});
```

Note: If you instead use `data`, it will read the entire upload into memory.

You could also create a custom [transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) to transform the incoming data, but that might not be trivial.

Comment: Should use on('readable'), not on('data'). The prior works efficiently. The later causes memory leaks.

Comment: Note that no parameter is sent for the 'readable' event - `buffer` is just a trick by the author to skip explicit variable declaration. It will always initially be `undefined`

Comment: @GershomMaes it's actually an artifact of the edit from @coolaj86 (`buffer` is declared inside the `for` loop so it's not a trick). I'll leave it for posterity.

Comment: Np! For the record I wasn't critiquing your style - I was just concerned for the poor dev who tries to use parameters sent from the `readable` event :)