# Firebase Storage + docxtemplater in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, docxtemplater

I am having trouble loading a firebase storage document in node js (preferably in binary) so that I can generate a docxtemplater document on it. I'm quite new to docxtemplater and would really like to use it for my webapp

Is this something that can be done?

Below is the code I get but I dont think it's loading the document from my firebase storage properly:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var PizZip = require('pizzip');
var Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
admin.initializeApp();
const BUCKET = 'gs://mpcwapp.appspot.com';

    const https = require('https');
    
    const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'myapp' });
    const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.test2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
// The error object contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a properties object containing all suberrors).
function replaceErrors(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Error) {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).reduce(function(error, key) {
            error[key] = value[key];
            return error;
        }, {});
    }
    return value;
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({error: error}, replaceErrors));

    if (error.properties && error.properties.errors instanceof Array) {
        const errorMessages = error.properties.errors.map(function (error) {
            return error.properties.explanation;
        }).join("\n");
        console.log('errorMessages', errorMessages);
        // errorMessages is a humanly readable message looking like this :
        // 'The tag beginning with "foobar" is unopened'
    }
    throw error;
}

//Load the docx file as a binary
let file_name = 'input.docx';
const myFile =storage.bucket(BUCKET).file(file_name);
var content =  myFile.createReadStream();

var zip = new PizZip(content);
var doc;
try {
    doc = new Docxtemplater(zip);
} catch(error) {
    // Catch compilation errors (errors caused by the compilation of the template : misplaced tags)
    errorHandler(error);
}

//set the templateVariables
doc.setData({
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    phone: '0652455478',
    description: 'New Website'
});

try {
    // render the document (replace all occurences of {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
    doc.render();
}
catch (error) {
    // Catch rendering errors (errors relating to the rendering of the template : angularParser throws an error)
    errorHandler(error);
}
var buf = doc.getZip()
             .generate({type: 'nodebuffer'});

buf.pipe(myFile.createWriteStream());

});
```

Any help will be appreciated I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're deploying your code logic in Firebase Functions, make sure it's inside your [list of exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions).

I tried to reproduce the behavior of your code and noticed that the root cause of the error is because of this part in your code:

```
var content =  myFile.createReadStream();
var zip = new PizZip(content);
```

pizzip appears to accept a **Buffer** input according to this [documentation](https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate.html). However, [`createReadStream()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createReadStream) returns **ReadableStream** so there's a mismatch between the required parameters.

There are two solutions I can think of:

1. First, download and store the file (in [`/tmp`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir)). Then read the file using `fs.readFileSync()`.
2. Skip saving the file to the file system and get the buffer of the file object.

For the 2nd option, you need to understand how streams work. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59276103/7031308) can give you a good head start. As example, you can get the buffer from ReadableStream like this:

```
const remoteFile = storage.bucket("bucket-name").file("file-name")
const readable = remoteFile.createReadStream()

var buffers = [];
readable.on('data', (buffer) => {
  buffers.push(buffer)
});
readable.on('end', () => {
  var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);  
  var zip = new PizZip(buffer);
  var doc;
  try {
      doc = new Docxtemplater(zip);
  } catch(error) {
      errorHandler(error);
  }

  // ... rest of your code
});
```

Comment: thank you @Dondi. It seems that a straightforward way to generate the document successfully is to get the buffer of `myFile` straight from the firebase storage instead of creating a ReadableStream in the first place or have i misunderstood?

Comment: @DejiJames you'll have to process the ReadableStream first to get the buffer, or as you said, get the buffer directly as discussed in this [GitHub answer](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/676#issuecomment-487710921).

Comment: @DejiJames I updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thanks a million i think it works now. I just keep getting the error `doc.pipe is not a function` but I am working to see where I made the error now.

Comment: Hi @Dondi just did. Thank you so much. I am really getting the hang on node js and firebase firestore off this project alone.